# Are setupvalue and upvaluejoin interchangeable (lua debug library)?

Tags: lua

Specifically, is there any difference (aside from the fact that setupvalue returns a name) between:

```
debug.setupvalue(f, up, val)
```

And

```
debug.upvaluejoin(f, up, function() return val end, 1)
```

(with val local)

Or between:

```
debug.upvaluejoin(f1, n1, f2, n2)
```

And

```
debug.setupvalue(f1, n1, select(2, debug.getupvalue(f2, n2)))
```

I was under the impression that upvaluejoin added some magic, but some testings suggest otherwise.

Is upvaluejoin just some sugar to ease function duplication and such?

Comment: `upvaluejoin` creates an "equvalence link" between two upvalues (and destroys already existing link, of course).  `setupvalue` does not create or break any links.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`debug.setupvalue(f, up, value)` sets `value` as the upvalue with id `up` of a function `f`

`whereas debug.upvaluejoin(f1, n1, f2, n2)` refers the `n1`-th upvalue of `f1` to the `n2`-th upvalue of `f2`

So actually they are completely different things, not just some sugar.

You could achieve the same results in some situations but they are definitely not the same or simply interchangable.

Comment: So with upvaluejoin latter join, if someone latter changes the value f2 is refering to, it will change the the value for f1, and setupvalue would not, if they are not "joined" (I want to say refering to the same closure, but I don't know if it's the correct term)?

what's more, does setupvalue also changes the value for any other function/chunk that might refer to that value?